# Remove Nvidia Card and switch to Intel HD graphics

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

today I removed my **GTX 750 Ti** card from my computer and enabled the internal **Intel HD graphics** in the BIOS. My computer boots just normal and everything seems to work fine until you try to login.

When you log in you simply land back on the login screen.

Do I need to set something special in my `xorg.conf` (which is currently empty) to use the iGPU?

The Nvidia drivers were uninstalled after the removal.

Answer (score 2):

I had to activate the Intel-driver

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Maybe this helps someone else!